# How to get my USB key to auto mount

Tags: mount, usb, devices

I'm currently working in a command line only environment.

When I plug my USB key in, I see a new device file in `/dev`:

```
...
sdi
sdi1
...
```

If I simply `sudo mount /dev/sdi1 /media/tmp`, and `umount` it when I'm done, I have to repeat the process all over again. This alone could be accomplished with a little script but my key doesn't always show up as `sdi`.

Is there a way for me to have it always auto-mount and maybe reserve `sdi` for it?

*Note:* Also, there seems to be orphaned device files in /dev if I forget to unmount and just pull the stick out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this [Udev rule from the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Auto_mounting_USB_devices):

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"

# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

# Global mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"

# Mount the device
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"

# Exit
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

Just change the "sd[a-z][0-9]" in the first line to avoid clashes with your other drives...

Comment: So all I do is place this in /etc/udev/rules.d/automount_usb.rules? Do I need a reboot?

Comment: Not according to the wiki: "Udev automatically detects changes to rule files, so changes take effect immediately without requiring udev to be restarted."

Answer (score 4):

On Debian and Ubuntu there is the package `usbmount` that should do exactly what you ask.

I am sure it is available in other Linux distros too.

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned I was on OpenSuse. `usbmount` isn't in the repos but I'm sure I could fine the source.

Comment: Source available on the usbmount home page :-) http://usbmount.alioth.debian.org/, it's dependencies are listed at http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/usbmount

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of auto-mount solutions out there, but I'd especially recommend those based on **`udev`** - like [uam](https://github.com/mgorny/uam/) for example.

Also, for normal user, command-line, on-demand mounting I'd recommend [`pmount`](http://pmount.alioth.debian.org/) (Policy based mounting programs that does not require any `sudo`).

Comment: Doesn't `pmount` require the obsolete `hal`?

Comment: Definitely not. It is a wrapper around `mount` that allows users mount just the removable media.