# How to give regular users the write privilege to an external drive?

Tags: scientific-linux, privileges, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mount permissions always blocked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21859/mount-permissions-always-blocked)

I'm using a scilinux machine. Whenever I connect an external drive, it is mounted as read only (and the root has full access). What and how should I edit to give a simple user the write privilege?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pmount` (policy-based "mount") lets you do that. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21859/mount-permissions-always-blocked) (possible duplicate).