# Where should I mount my external harddrive?

Tags: arch-linux, mount, conventions

I've got an external harddrive that I'd like to auto-mount. It will be present most times when my laptop boots. Where is the "correct" place to mount it?

- `/media/my-hd`: Will litter `/media` with an empty folder when the hard-drive was not mounted.
- `/mnt/my-hd`: I've heard that `/mnt` itself is supposed to be used as a temporary mount point. This happens, for example, during the Arch installation process.

Comment: If you use a udev rule to automount, there won't be any empty folders "littering" `/media` when the drive is unmounted...

Comment: You could certainly make the mount point directory mode 0500 owner root:root, and the root directory on the drive something like 0755 owner you:users. That would largely ensure that you don't accidentally save things there when the drive is not mounted, and wonder where they ended up...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommendation in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) is that [`/media`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MEDIAMOUNTPOINT) contains subdirectories for mount points of removable media. There are two conflicting traditions about `/mnt`: some consider it a mount point, whereas others consider it a directory for mount points. The FHS requests that distributions leave `/mnt` alone, so that the administrator can do what they like with it, and set up mount points under `/media`. System installation is a special case: it's a dedicated system, so it doesn't need to worry about competing conventions.

If you use an automounting script (such as an udev rule as suggested by jasonwryan 
 — see [How to get my USB key to auto mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21044/how-to-get-my-usb-key-to-auto-mount)), it can take care of creating the mount point. But there's no harm in having the mount point all the time.

Comment: I'm having a similar situation, that differs in that the system in question is a server running from microSD, having an external hard drive as a larger storage for non-system files, and the mount is pretty much fixed/permanent. My intention is to soft-link appropriate files and directories under, for example, /srv as I see fit.
I *think* that your answer clears up my problem, and I assume that the correct mount point is under /media. In case I've misunderstood or you have something to say about this, let me know and I'll write a question and notify you about it so you can give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR `/mnt/my-hd`

The Linux Filesystem Hierarchy conventions are documented over at [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/).

The `/media` entry reads,

> Amid much controversy and consternation on the part of system and network administrators a directory containing mount points for removable media has now been created.

Your hard drive isn't removable media, so it should be mounted under `/mnt`.

That being said, it really is up to you. On a personal system, it really doesn't matter!

Comment: This answer makes no sense: the distinction between `/mnt` and `/media` is not about removable vs non-removable media. Besides we're talking about a removable media here.