# umount an external ntfs drive as non-root

Tags: non-root-user, unmounting, ntfs-3g

I have [ntfs-3g](http://wiki.debian.org/NTFS/) installed, and use [this udev rule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21049/261) to auto mount external drives automatically. When I try umount it as non-root, it says:

```
umount: /media/umm is not in the fstab (and you are not root)
```

The device mounts as:

```
/dev/sdc1  fuseblk    150G  143G  6.6G  96% /media/umm
```

and is part of the `users` group. I did a `chkdsk` on a Windows machine to ensure no file system errors.

Any ideas?

(personally I'd prefer not to use ntfs, but I need it for sharing with all the non-UNIX systems and allow for files > 4GB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the system is designed.

Since the filesystem is being mounted by root and it's not listed in `/etc/fstab` with the `user` option, only root can unmount it. You can't change this behavior.

What you *can* do is to modify your script to mount it in a location you own as your user. You'll also need to make the block device readable/writable by you.

That would be to change this:

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"
```

To this:

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/chown invert:invert /dev/%k", RUN+="sudo -u invert /bin/mkdir -p /home/invert/media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="sudo -u invert /bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /home/invert/media/%E{dir_name}"
```

Giving users direct read/write access to block devices is not something to be encouraged, but if this is only your workstation the reduction in security is probably negligible.

Comment: I'm happy to do this on my personal netbook. I will try this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ubuntu`, I think using `disk utility` (actually made by `RedHat`) will do it just fine

Comment: I do not have `disk utility` on Crunchbang Linux, I would prefer a  more cross-distro solution please.

Comment: k. sorry, not sure how to without using this tool.