# How can I auto-mount my MicroSD?

Tags: debian, automounting

I'm rather new to Linux, I'll be up front about that, but I've sort of run face first into a wall on this one.
I've just set up Samba on the server so that I can access my MicroSD card over the network from my Windows computer, because the Windows doesn't have a reader, and the Debian server does. My goal then, was that I could plug in the SD card to the server without having to log in and mount the card. Just connect via. Samba and modify the card. Done. I can connect to the Samba server perfectly, and to the microSD card, however to connect to the card, I first need to log into the system locally and manually mount the card as opposed to my desired functionality: plug the chip into the idling Debian server (Running, but screen off. It's a webserver, so it's never in real standby..) and then just hop on to the windows desktop and play with the chip from there.

To try and remedy this, I've attempted to add the rule from this answer:
[How to get my USB key to auto mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21044/how-to-get-my-usb-key-to-auto-mount)

only to find absolutely no effect. File in the correct location, system rebooted to allow Udev to try and find the new rule, nothing happens.
Searching further, I found this similar answer:
[Automount USB drives with no GUI requirement (halevt replacement)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11472/automount-usb-drives-with-no-gui-requirement-halevt-replacement)

which offered the same Udev rule, but more information leading me to Udisks wrappers, which led me to "udiskie" which seems to be a perfect solution for me.
And there's the wall. For whatever reason, my Debian installation can't find any of the required python packages listed in the UDiskie install page here:
https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/wiki/Ubuntu-Debian-installation-guide

And going to packages.debian.org to find, download, and install the packages via. wget and dpkg only resulted in dependancy errors related to me not having a Python installation between 2.7 and 2.8, (>= 2.7, << 2.8) where "python --version" tells me that I have 2.7.3 installed.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, this is making no sense to me whatsoever...
I'm on Debian 7.6.0, not sure which codename that one is exactly. xD

Comment: What you're asking for *really* asks for a `udev` rule. Look [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9311) for what I used when I was learning. It is dated, but it is an excellent start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, I was able tonight to `apt-get install autofs`, where I wasn't able earlier.
After some quick configuration, my issues are completely resolved.

For those interested, once I had `autofs` actually installed, I simply had to add

```
/media /etc/auto.removable --timeout=2
```

to `/etc/auto.master`, and then create a new file (`/etc/auto.removable`) containing:

```
MICRO -fstype=auto,uid=1000,sync,nodev,nosuid :/dev/sdf1
```

This allows me to plug in the microSD, then access it via. a network shortcut (thanks Samba). The device isn't visibly mounted until I access it, but once it is, it appears under `/media/MICRO`. `/dev/sdf1` is the name of the MicroSD device, `uid` is set that I can read and write to the device as myself instead of the device mounting as root and it being read-only, if it'd be readable at all. The device then automatically unmounts 2 seconds after I close the window on the Windows machine.
It'd be nice if I didn't need to use a shortcut to access the folder, what with the folder not existing until accessed, but this is a nice solution. Figured I'd share it.

Answer (score 0):

In the distros , that its make with a Daemon like : Hal , in the oldest distros, i not secure with the lastest distros .

If the trouble its mount an appear in samba , you need share the folder in you distro , i ever share /media/externals/

i put the usd , sd's , compact discs , in the /media/externals
and my anothers partitions harddrives in /media/internals

you should share the /media/externals , editing the "/etc/samba/smb.conf" to make the configuration you need and share the folder you wanna shared trought Windows & Linux , for me it works properly

Comment: Sorry, I knew I should have specified; the problem is not that the disk won't share through Samba, that's working fine. The issue is that I need to log into the Debian system to mount the disk manually before I can access it on the Windows system.